# how to set the default version of tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

everybody,

I met a problem that I install two version of TensorFlow as the figure below.

[two versions of tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2XaF.png)

[image]

The default version is TensorFlow 1.1.0. see below.

[the default version of tensorflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhak9.png)

[image]

How to change the default version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have more than 1 version of Tensorflow on your system, you should create virtual environments for each version. You can use [virtualenv](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup#virtualenv_installation) or anaconda environments.If you want to just use one version, just `pip uninstall` the other.

**EDIT** Im using a [guide](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) from here. If using anaconda virtual environment, create a new environment with a python version `x.x` of your choice. It will prompt you with all the default python dependencies anaconda will install in your environment.

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

Add any other packages you want in your virtual environment, e.g. tensorflow-gpu

```
conda install -n yourenvname tensorflow-gpu
```

To check if tensorflow is correctly installed in the environemnts, you can use `conda list` while your environment is activated with `source activate yourenvname` to check if only 1 tensorflow is installed. Repeat the above steps if you intend to use different versions of tensorflow, e.g. cpu and gpu versions. You may also need to change your python interpreter to the python of your environment, in your editor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do actually want to create virtual environments of Anaconda. I created and activated a new environment using the command "conda create -n tensorflow_gpu; source activate tensorflow_gpu". And then I installed the tensorflow using command "pip install  --ignore-installed --upgrade https://xxxx". But there was no lib installed in the env tensorflow_gpu. The lib was installed outside tensorflow_gpu. Any suggestion?

Comment: `pip` installs tensorflow on your default python environment, not your virtual environment. I believe that you are missing a step in creating your virtual environment, i will update my answer with that.

Comment: I solved the problem by run the command "conda install pip" before run "pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade xxxx". I finally could find the tensorflow lib in the virtual environment. Thank for your reply. @Joshua Lim

Comment: I only install the tensorflow-gpu lib. I can disable the GPU if I don't want to use GPU by the command 'import os;os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID";os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use tensorflow with gpu, just uninstall `tensorflow` and keep `tensorflow-gpu`. Then, you will get the gpu version when do `import tensorflow`.

Also, the latest tf gpu version is 1.1.0. You can upgrade it with `conda` or `pip`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I uninstalled the tensorflow-gpu using command "pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu". But I got a mistake message that was "ImportError: No module named tensorflow" when I import tensorflow. What's wrong with my operation?

Comment: Do you still get tensorflow in pip list?

Comment: pip installs/uninstalls tensorflow on my default python environment. I solved this problem by creating a new virtual environment--"conda create -n tensorflow_gpu; source activate tensorflow_gpu". I updated the pip by command "conda install pip" before installing the tensorflow lib. Thanks for your reply. @frankyjuang

Comment: How do you get the cpu version if you installed `tensorflow-gpu`?